# reading data in react native with firebase

Tags: typescript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently stuck with reading data from firebase with my react native app. Here is my code and a screenshot of my database structure. Very basic for the test: just reading the address of an user and set it as a state when the button is clicked.

Well, this is not working at all because thé returned value is null... What am I doing wrong?

```
export default class Test extends React.Component {
state = {headerText: 'caca'}

onButtonPressed() {
this.database = firebase.database();
const userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;          
firebase.database().ref(`/users/bucheurs/${userId}/infos/adresse`).on("value", snapshot => {
this.setState({headerText: snapshot.val()})
 })
}
render() {

return (
 <View style={{
   flex: 1
 }}>
   <View style={styles.headerView}>
     <Header
      centerComponent={{
      text: this.state.headerText,
      style: {
      color: 'white',
      fontSize: 20
      }
    }} 
    style={styles.header}/>
  </View>
  <Button 
    title='GO' backgroundColor={secondary} 
    onPress={this.onButtonPressed.bind(this)}/>
</View>
```

)
};
}

My database structure:

[image]

Comment: What isn't working? Is there an error? Component fails to render?

Comment: hey Dan,
the components renders fine, so as everything; the only problem is that the value returned is null.

Comment: Can you update your post with the full component code please?

Comment: Done! ps i'm using react native elements for the header and the button.

Comment: Did you console log userId for be sure that it is defined ? Also try to access to /users/bucheurs/${userId}/infos/ if you can access all the value from infos

Comment: i tried yes: the userId is well defined no problem from there. 

but if i write this path, how firebase will know i want to fetch specifically the adresse value ?

Comment: @ArnaudDerbey I said try for try something for fix your problem. If you can access to all infos data and you can't access only addresse it give us more informations

Comment: @GabrielDiez I understand and i think the problem come from the '${userId}/infos/adresse' part. I can read data from '/users/bucheurs' but not after that; even if can can console.log the uid. Do you have any idea how to write this path part in an other way ?

Comment: @ArnaudDerbey Can you put your permissions you set to your database? in database -> rules

Comment: permissions are set like this for now:
{
  "rules":{
   ".read": true,
  ".write": true
}
}

Comment: That's the only permissions you have ?

Comment: @GabrielDiez yep the only one... For now 'course ^^

Answer (score 1):

I find the answer this morning after to day of insomnia ! :D

that was the "userId" part wich was wrong.

the ref has to be written this way :

```
ref(`users/bucheurs/ + ${userId} + /infos/adresse`)
```

Hope this can help some react-native / firebase devs. Thanks you all for your comments. <3

Comment: OK that's weird ... This is the only way i can catch a value. Does this syntax works as well ?